# Unit testing with rspec2 and Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, nokogiri, rspec2

I have a requirement to read a third-party public website. Currently I am able to do this via Nokogiri, but I'm having trouble writing some unit tests using rspec.

I have this HTML `<div>`:

```
<div class="user">
  <div class="name">User Name</div>
</div>
```

In my Reader model I have the method `name`, which reads the name from the HTML:

```
class SampleReader
    def name(html_div)
      html_div.css('name')
    end
end
```

In my RSpec test case I pass the above HTML `<div>` as a string to the `name` method and I get the following error:

```
undefined method `css' for #<String:0x007fd8a0b39c98>
```

I believe it's because Nokogiri cannot identified the string as HTML, so I would appreciate if someone can help me write the test case.  And, if possible, my preferred option is to pass only the `<div>` string, not the entire HTML page source, to the method.

- I'm using Rails 3.2.9
- Rspec2
- Nokogiri

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to wrap the HTML string as a Nokogiri document:

```
require 'nokogiri'

str = <<-HTML
<div class="user">
  <div class="name">User Name</div>
</div>
HTML

class SampleReader
  def name(html_div)
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html_div)
    doc.css('.name').text
  end
end

reader = SampleReader.new
puts reader.name(str) #=> "User Name"
```

Also, don't forget to [upgrade your application to rails 3.2.11](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2013/1/8/Rails-3-2-11-3-1-10-3-0-19-and-2-3-15-have-been-released/).